# BotFramework: Block specific user IP

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to create an anti-spam block in my bot implementation to avoid a spike in infrastructure costs, so I configured in my Azure Function the IP Restriction Rules, available via the ResourceManager API and the portal networking configuration.

My goal is to make sure the user won't be able to communicate with my bot if more than X messages are sent.

**The issue**: I've configured the external IP restriction for my own PC and allowed all the others (see code example below), but I can still talk to my bot.

**Question 1**: am I doing something wrong?

**Question 2**: I wonder if the IP Restriction don't work because the user communicates with the bot through DirectLine, so the bot doesn't receive any request from the user directly. If that's the reason, how could I block the client from contacting DirectLine with a **server side solution**?

Please find below some details about my bot infrastructure...

**Client:**

- BotFramework-Webchat
- Channel:

  - DirectLine

**Server:**

- Botservice composed of:

  - Consumption App Service
  - Azure Function running the bot code

**Goals:**

- when a user sends more than X messages, block any communication
  coming from that specific user (I'm not interested in blocking a
  range of IPs)
- the user should be blocked on the server side

**Current IP Restriction setup (not working):**

```
...
"ipSecurityRestrictions": [
      {
        "ipAddress": "X.X.X.X/32",  <-- specific user's external IP
        "action": "Deny",
        "tag": "Default",
        "priority": 1,
        "name": "Ban Me"
      },
      {
        "ipAddress": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "action": "Allow",
        "tag": "Default",
        "priority": 300,
        "name": "Allow others"
      }
    ],
...
```

Comment: `the user communicates with the bot through DirectLine, so the bot doesn't receive any request from the user directly.` As you mentioned, the bot application does not receive request from the user directly, configuring IP Restrictions would not work as expected. If possible, you can maintain a counter of messages for each user and store it in UserData, and then you can check if the counter of messages exceed the maximum limitation before you send response to that user.

Comment: Hi @FeiHan, I already implemented that kind of counter in place, but I would like something that is more system wide: each request means Functions execution that are useless. So I wonder if there is a way to block the user earlier, maybe removing his access to the DirectLine itself? But I don't want to do it on the Javascript as that is easily hackable...

Comment: Isn't there anyone who can give me ( or direct me to) more information about administering Azure Direct Line to solve my problem?